# Laravel is not updating the views or any things

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am using laravel verison 7.28.3  and it was working perfectly without any problem, now  I am changing some things in the view or even javascript files but can not see the changes in the browser, even I removed all the code in the view but still show the old version,
I tried with all familiar clear command like these but not effect

```
PHP artisan cache:clear
PHP artisan config:clear 
PHP artisane view clear 
PHP artisan route:clear
```

and even I removed all file inside `storage/framework/views/`
but still no effect
I tried by removing all routes in web.php file but the project still working and it can reload
what should I do please I need to apply my changes.

Comment: Use this command php artisan view:clear, or if you have already done that then  go to storage/framework/views folder and delete all the files inside the view folder

Comment: force reload the server response from your browser. On chrome; open dev tools (ctrl + shift + i ) right click the reload button on the top left of the webpage window and choose "Empty cache and hard reload"

Comment: thank you for your reply any way  I dud reload force but it is not working , as I set the blade page to be blank (empty ) but it still working , that making me crazy

Comment: @KhalidKhan I already  did  all of these but without result, the project still working in cache

Comment: Happened to me once. I restarted my system. Try restarting your system

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, the problem may be caused by:

After installing Laravel, you may have switched to vue ui after installing default ui or bootstrap ui. If you don't have a cache problem, you are editing a wrong file. Check this directory and edit this files.

```
resources/js/Pages
```

If that's not your problem, check your cache settings in your laravel config file.

```
config/cache.php
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, you may be having problems with the opcache. Find your php.ini file and disable opcache.

And dont forget run this command for changes in vue files to take effect

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: And dont forget run this command for changes in vue files to take effect: npm run dev

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with opcache in .ini . I disabled (;) all opcache settings, removed ./opache folder
then:

```
php artisan optimize:clear                                    
php artisan event:cache                                                             
php artisan view:cache                                                              
php artisan optimize                                                                 
npm run build
```

then:
sync with website host
then a PageSpeed Insights test.

Results: no increase or decrease in speed for my website. Score: 100

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to

> storage/framework/views

2. Delete all files
3. Refresh your page and its done.